# Insert a MultiPolygon in a PostGIS table with MapInfo?

Tags: postgis, polygon, editing, mapinfo, odbc

I'm using MapInfo 16 to edit a PostGIS table through ODBC driver.
The geometry column type of my table is `MultiPolygon`.
The value in `spatialtype` colmun of a record in `mapinfo.mapinfo_mapcatalog` table is `19.2`. That stands for MapInfo `region` type AFAIK.

When I'm hitting a `Save Table` button, I get an ODBC Error:

`Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon);`

So I guess MapInfo is trying to insert a Polygon geometry into a MultiPolygon column. Converting new created features to regions doesn't help.

The only workaround I can think of is to set a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on this table with something like 

`NEW.geom := st_multi(NEW.geom);`

But it doesn't seem like a natural solution. 
Maybe I'm missing something in MapInfo options?

**UPDATE**:Proposed trigger solution doesn't work. Seems like type checking happens earlier than trigger fires.

Comment: If "region" stands for both polygons and multipolygons for MapInfo then your solution feels good to me. Another option would be to create the geometry column in PostGIS as general "GEOMETRY".

Comment: Trigger doesn't work. It seems to be fired after type checking. A general "GEOMETRY" is another workaround, but then I'll have problems with editing by QGIS etc.

Comment: If you do not have real multipart polygons you could change the PostGIS table into "POLYGON" then.

Comment: I do have multipolygons in my table. That is why it's of MultiPolygon type. Some of them have only one geometry, but often not. Splitting a table into polys and multipolys isn't convenient either.

Comment: Doesn't PostGIS allow you to insert Polygon as well as MultiPolygon into a table? In MapInfo Pro a Region basically can be both.

Comment: Postgis has strict geometry types and doesn't allow to insert polys to multipoly table. It does allow to insert multipoly with just one geom.